# jquery export table csv ,pdf

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatables

I have a table in jquery I want to export this table in csv, pdf, excel I tried this method in my controller:
but she displays the contents of the page ok.twig.html

```
public function adminCsvAction() { 
     $session =$this->get('request')->getSession() ;
    $user_name = $session->get('user_name');
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM AdminBlogBundle:AlertesBss2 u  where u.cmts  IS  NULL AND NOT EXISTS  (SELECT p.cmts FROM AdminBlogBundle:DarkCell p WHERE p.cmts != u.cmts)');
$listes = $query->getResult();

$filename = "export_".date("Y_m_d").".csv"; 

$response = $this->render('AdminBlogBundle:GestionAlerte:ok.html.twig', array('listes'=>$listes)); 
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');

$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$filename); 
return  $response;
```

}
who can help me

Comment: the table is created via jquery?

Comment: yes my table is created vi jquery

Answer (score 2):

I wold recommend using [DataTable](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/) jQuery plugin, for export, especially if you are considering multiple formats. Will save you time as oppose to reinvent the wheel

Comment: if the response was favorable why aren't you using it?